# Longest substring of alternating characters in a string

Tags: algorithm, recursion, search, divide-and-conquer

I've been going around this Divide and conquer problem of given a string made of lowcase characters, find the longest substring made of contiguous {consonant, vowel} and it's position on the string.

Example.

string = "ehbabebaehehehbe"

solution = "babeba" position: 3

I've tried a lot of things and i've found these problems.

1. I don't know where to split the problem, cause i may split the solution, and merging the subsolutions, the solution could disappear
2. When merging the subsolutions, i dont know if i should combine them or choose one of them because i dont know if they are contiguous

Comment: You could use an approach similar to *maximum subarray sum problem*. It does have a divide and conquer approach. I think this problem and that problem do share some similarity.

Comment: Is a Divide and Conquer algorithm mandatory? Because a simple O(N) solution also exists

Comment: Yes, as i'm practicing DyV approach to algorithms, is it mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given some time to your problem. I have come up with an algorithm. Here are the details.

---

### Concept

We will use two methods:

```
1: int[] maxSubstringOfAlternatingCharacters(String string, int low, int high)
```

In this method, *we simply divide the string into two parts. We will be dividing the string from the middle*. This method *returns an array* of the form `{startIndex, substringLength}`.

```
2: int[] maxCrossingSubstring(String string, int low, int mid, int high)
```

In this method, *we find the substring of maximum length having alternate characters between low and high*. This method *returns an array* of the form `{startIndex, substringLength}`.

---

### Algorithm

**Method 1:**

```
1:  int[] maxSubstringOfAlternatingCharacters(String string, int low, int high)
2:
3:      if (low == high) return {low, 1}
4:      
5:      mid = (low + high)/2
6:      leftSubstring = maxSubstringOfAlternatingCharacters(string, low, mid)
7:      rightSubstring = maxSubstringOfAlternatingCharacters(string, mid+1, high)
8:      crossingSubstring = maxCrossingSubstring (string, low, mid, high)
9:
10:     if leftSubstring[1] >= rightSubstring[1] and leftSubstring[1] >= crossingSubstring[1]
11:         return leftSubstring
12:     else if rightSubstring[1] >= leftSubstring[1] and rightSubstring[1] >= crossingSubstring[1]
13:         return rightSubstring
14:     else
15:         return crossingSubstring
```

**Method 2:**

```
1:  int[] maxCrossingSubstring (String string, int low, int mid, int high)
2:
3:      if char[mid] and char[mid+1] are not alternating characters
4:          return {low, 0};
5:
6:      leftMaxSubstring = 1;
7:      //Loop from mid to low to find leftMaxSubstring of alternating characters*/
8:      rightMaxSubstring = 1;
9:      //Loop from mid+1 to high to find rightMaxSubstring of alternating characters*/
10:     return {mid-leftMaxSubstring+1, leftMaxSubstring+rightMaxSubstring}
```

---

### Time complexity

The *divide step* takes `O(1)` time. The *combine step*, that is, finding the max crossing substring takes at worst `O(n)` time where `n` is `high-low+1`.

The *recurrence relation* will be:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)
```

which results in a time complexity of `O(n*logn)`.

---

### Final Thoughts

I did not provide the complete implementation of `maxCrossingSubstring` method. *You should try to do it on your own. If you face any problem, do comment and I will complete it too*. If you face any trouble understanding any part of the algorithm, do comment and I will update my answer to help you.

*I think there might be a faster algorithm to solve your problem which will run in `O(n)`*. It will be similar to the `Kadane's algorithm` and hence it will **not** be a *Divide and Conquer algorithm*.

I hope I have helped you. *I did implement this algorithm myself and it did work for me against many inputs. If anyone find anything wrong with it. Do comment.*

Comment: This is such a great response. Thank you very much, i was coming to a similar solution with your suggestion of the maximum subarray. Also, i made previously that faster algorithm you mention in O(n) searching for ideas to solve this. Again, thank you very much for your time.